# How can i block all the other ISR requests, except the one that i'm in.

Tags: assembly, assemblies

...

```
     ;counter1 init
    mov al, 01110100b       
    out 063h, al

     ;counter2 init
    mov al, 10010100b       
    out 063h, al
```

...

```
; ISR executed when count2 ends                                 
ISR_COUNT12 PROC               
            cli
              ;procedure to be protected from the other ISR interrupts


            sti

            IRET
ISR_COUNT12 ENDP
```

I need to re-execute ISR_COUNT12 after each time counter12(PIC-8253) has finished counting..
ISR_COUNT12 gets called evry time the counter2 becomes 0.

Comment: I want to disable all the software interrupts except the one assigned to the counter (ISR_COUNT12). How can i mask the interrupt with index "34" in interrupt vector table in order to not be affected when using CLI / STI??

Comment: To be honset, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to **mask** software interrupts..